# How to disable the initial connection line to the last point in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, fl-chart

In Flutter Web, I have written the following code to draw a chart, which is used from the fl_chart: ^0.62.0 package. :

```
LineChart(
                                LineChartData(
                                  lineTouchData: touchSpotChart(),
                                  titlesData: chartTitleData(),
                                  lineBarsData: [
                                    LineChartBarData(
                                      color: Colors.green,
                                      aboveBarData: BarAreaData(
                                        applyCutOffY: false,
                                        show: true,
                                        color: Colors.white70,
                                        spotsLine: null,
                                      ),
                                      spots: _manualOrImportingChoice ? myExcelSpot : mySingleStateSpotData,
                                      isStepLineChart: false,
                                      isCurved: false,
                                      dotData: FlDotData(
                                        show: false,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
```

The problem I have is connecting the first to the last point of the graph that you can see its photo below: [chart problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4QB9.jpg)

Thank you for your advice on how to remove this line.